# Python, Selenium and Chrome: cannot load page, because of "Not secure" warning

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a webpage through Python, Selenium and Chrome. The code is:

```
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "http://some-proxy.net:8090"
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-automation")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-save-password-bubble")
chrome_options.add_argument("test-type")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("test-type=browser")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver_path = 'M:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options,desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://somepage.csintra.net/')
```

Chrome will open, but not load the page. Instead, I get the following "Not secure" warning displayed:

[image]

As per code above, I have tried disabling various Chrome options gathered from various SO answers, but to no avail. I have also tried `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d), but this causes the following error in chromedriver.exe:

> Failed to resolve service name: metrics

As visible on the screenshot above, I also cannot unblock notifications, popups and location upon Selenium opening Chrome, since they are blocked by administrator - I am doing this at work (but anyway, in my Chrome settings "[*].csintra.net" is allowed to open popups and notifications).

Python's console output when the code is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-82760f33374f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('M:/python scripts/coding_automation.py', wdir='M:/python scripts')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "M:/python scripts/coding_automation.py", line 35, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options,desired_capabilities=capabilities)

  File "C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

  File "C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

  File "C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

  File "C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\M299700\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Is there any way to bypass this?

EDIT:

As mentioned above, solution posted in the "duplicate "thread did not help.

Comment: I don't think you need to prefix arguments with `--`

Comment: Thanks Harry. I tried removing the `--` but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

i feel like you have to throw an exception and check some kind of call it makes. either that or know the type of div the error screen is and check with a DoesNotExist rabbit hole.